# Double VLOOKUP based on the same column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to VLookup items from a Column D to extract info from 2 different sheets within the same Excel File. I ran 2 separate macros for each file. Combining them and running separately has caused the same issue and I need help to hopefully run the 2 VLookups smoothly such that any input in Column D, I will always get a proper lookup output in Column H from both sheets

This was made with Vlookup1 for Sheet 1, where it showed the results of A to C that had corresponding values in Sheet 1. it showed #N/A for values that were from Sheet 2
[image: If Vlookup 1 was used]

This was when Vlookup2 was ran
[image: If Vlookup 2 was used]

```
Sub VLookup()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Find the last row in column D
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each row and perform the VLOOKUP
    For i = 6 To lastRow
        ' Get the lookup value from column G
        Dim lookupValue As Variant
        lookupValue = Cells(i, "G").Value
        
        ' Perform VLOOKUP and insert the result into the corresponding N cell
        Cells(i, "H").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(D" & i & ",'Sheet1'!G:AJ,25,FALSE)"
    Next i
  
     If IsError(result) Then
        
        ' Perform VLOOKUP and insert the result into the corresponding N cell
        Cells(i, "H").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(D" & i & ",'Sheet2'!H:AJ,25,FALSE)"
        
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I'm not sure if my if statement was correct. It's definitely not the best or the right one but it still resulted in this

[image: code result]

Comment: You could combine both vlokkups inside one IFERROR, something like `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP_1, VLOOKUP_2)`

Comment: How do I do this in a macro? I can't just =IFERROR(VLOOKUP_1, VLOOKUP_2) in the Visual Basic code

Comment: Try first doing it manually and then record a macro and see how the recorder does it.

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about. I just tried, and the code does not work "manually" . I did mention that I'm looking for help with the VBA code here for a macro, not inputting manually. Sorry.

Comment: When I mean manually I mean with normal formulas in Excel. Then, once you got the solution, you can use the macro recorder to see the VBA code for your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next code and send some feedback after testing it:

```
Sub DoubleVlookup()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngG As Range
  
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  lastR = ws.Range("D" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  
  Set rngG = ws.Range("G6:G" & lastR) 

   ws.Range("H6:H" & lastR).Formula = "=IfError(Vlookup(" & rngG.cells(1).address(0, 0) & _
        ",'Sheet1'!G:AJ,25,FALSE),VLOOKUP(" & rngG.cells(1).address(0, 0) & ",'Sheet2'!H:AJ,25,FALSE))"  
End Sub
```

Comment: @ISuckAtCoding Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?